# With React Router v4, how to navigate to a path based upon the existing browser location but with new params interpolated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

## Goal

How do I create a onChange handler for the select menu in a parent component to be aware of the current location of a sub route and push to a new path with a path param replaced?

For example… when on the url `/users/1/foo/bar` and then selecting user 2 in a html select, I'd like to navigate to `/users/2/foo/bar`.

---

## Current Setup

Let's say I have the following route:

```
<Route path="/users/:userId" component={UserIndex} />
```

Which has the following sub routes:

```
<Route path="/users/:userId/foo" component={UserFoo} />
<Route path="/users/:userId/foo/bar" component={UserFooBar} />
```

In the `UserIndex` component I have a html select element which has a list of users.

```
<select onChange={this.changeUser}>
  <option value="1">User 1</option>
  <option value="2">User 2</option>
  <option value="3">User 3</option>
</select>
```

---

## Initial Attempt

I tried using `string.replace()` on the `match.path` value:

```
changeUser = (event) => {
  const { match, history } = this.props
  history.push(match.path.replace(':userId', event.target.value))
}
```

…but in the `UserIndex` component where the select is rendered, the value of `match.path` is `/users/:userId` which does not contain the rest of the path after the `userId`: "foo", "foo/bar", etc.

---

## *Fragile* Working Solution

A fragile, but working solution is to use `location.pathname` and update part of the array by element number:

```
changeUser = (event) => {
  const {
    history,
    location,
  } = this.props
  const paths = location.pathname.split('/')
  paths[2] = event.target.value
  history.push(paths.join('/'))
}
```

But what if the element number changes? Ack!

---

## Is there a better and less-fragile way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of information from `props.match` and `props.location`

First, extract the position of the parameter from `match`

```
let position = this.props.match.path.split('/').indexOf(':userId');
```

Use this position, to change location.

```
let transformedPath = this.props.location.pathname.split('/')
transformedPath[position] = newValue;
this.props.history.push(trasnformedPath.join('/'))
```

Comment: `indexOf`!!  Oh duh! If no other answers come in showing how to do this natively in React Router v4, I'll accept this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it with React Router 4

https://reactrouter.com/core/api/match

```
  const {
    props.params: { userId },
  } = match;
```